# Can't connect to MySQL server on Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

I've just launched a MariaDB instance on RDS. I used all the default options, on the free tier. It has finished creating. When I try to access it with Sequel Pro or with the command line, I get an error:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on {endpoint}

My security group is the default group. Its Inbound and Outbound Rules have:

- Type: ALL Traffic
- Protocol: ALL
- Port Range: ALL

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you enable the "Publicly Accessible" flag? If not, it will only be accessible from within the VPC.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, it's Publicly Accessible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer for me was to add a new Inbound Rule to my existing Security Group:

- Type: MySQL/Aurora (3306)
- Protocol: TCP (6)
- Port Range: 3306
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

[EDIT Oct 2020]: See Leon's comment below. Instead of `0.0.0.0/0` use your specific IP address.

Comment: you should use your specific IP address, suffixed with "/32" (and change it when needed), rather than 0.0.0.0/0 . this can be done through console in EC2 > security groups > inbound

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the instance have an internet ip? If not, you know, you can
   only connect it from inner net.
2. The port is 3306?